# How to convert map to string in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table like follows

```
CREATE TABLE $NAMESPACE.artist_seed_to_albums_nn(
id STRING,
vals MAP<STRING, FLOAT>
)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t'
collection items terminated by ','
map keys terminated by ':'
stored as textfile
..
```

So, a row is like

```
"foo" \t {"foo": 0.2, "bar":0.6}
```

I want to convert the map to string like

```
"foo" \t "foo:02,bar:0.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way without using third-party UDF is to define column in the table DDL as STRING:

```
vals string
```

Then you can remove extra characters if necessary `["{}]` from the string during select:

```
select select regexp_replace(vals,'["{}]','') as vals
```

Also you can use [Brickhouse to_json](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Json-udfs) for converting arbitrary Hive structure to JSON string. And after that, remove extra characters.

First method is better because vals column values will be deserialized by SerDe as STRING (as is), no additional transformation required.